# Histogram not showing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to draw a histogram using matplotlib.The problem is i dont understand why my histogram wont show, the axis are drawn and labelled but there is no graph shown(see image below), below is my code.Please tell me how to resolve this.

```
      val=list(movie['Year'].value_counts().values)
        #movie is a dataframe and in this case val has following values
       #[297, 127, 98, 91, 64, 63, 60, 53, 52, 51, 44]



        plt.hist(val) #val is a list
       
        plt.ylim([2006,2016])

        plt.yticks(np.arange(2006, 2017, 1))


         plt.show()
```

[image: My Output]

Comment: its a list of numbers

Comment: val=list(movie['Year'].value_counts().values)

Comment: This is how i am populating val, movie is a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Given your information, My guess is, you're confusing what a histogram is. A histogram basically counts how many given values fall within a given range.
So in your problem, you shouldn't count the frequencies of the movie year, the histogram will do that for you. Like this

```
year_list = [...] #contains year
plt.hist(year,bins,histtype,....) #hist method parameters
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ylim` and `yticks` and you should see your histogram.

In the example you give, the y limits you set (2006-2016) are at odds with the data (counts in each bin).  The number of elements in `val`, 11 , is far smaller than the minimum (2006) you have set.

In addition, as pointed out by @SifatAmin, you may want to check how a histogram works.